# SQL Server 2016 always encrypted. can i use always encrypted for data warehouse. if not then what optioins do i have?

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, always-encrypted

I am working with SQL Server 2016 SP1 standard edition.
I am looking for options or best option to encrypt data warehouse.
I have tried SQL server symmetric key encryption but using view to decrypt it is like full circle and it is not fully secure.
I cannot use TDE because of standard edition.
I cannot use always encrypted because it is for Client / server.

Comment: Hi, i think you have to use stored procedure to do that what you want.

Comment: I have used stored procedure but it is not fully secure.

Comment: I didn’t see why’s not secure by using stored procedure ? Stored procedure was safe for me you can alow user you want to execute thoses and user doesn’t have to access table.

Comment: just trying to hide everything and trying to get more control over this process. with stored procedure there will be performance issue also.

Comment: There is no such thing like "fully secure". To get a meaningful answer, first you must define from whom you are trying to protect your data. Otherwise your question will probably be closed.